# Consulta al servicio de forma asíncrona

Tags: angular, webservice, promesas, devexpress, asincronismo

Soy nuevo en angular, tengo un problema en un método que hace una consulta a mi servicio desarrollado con servicesStack, lo esta haciendo de forma síncrona y quisiera que que fuera de forma asíncrona, mi metodo es este:

```
async getAllContries() {
    try{
        this.paisRQ = new PaisRQ();
        this.paisRQ.ActionRQ = 'get';
        this.paisRQ.Idioma = 'SP';
        return await this.service.getAllCountries(this.paisRQ)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => {
            this.dataSource = res.ListPaisCovid;
            this.mappingObjectVector();
    });
    } catch (error){}
    
}
```

aqui lleno mi request, y consulto al servicio la estructura del servicio la tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
public getAllCountries(data: PaisRQ): Observable<PaisCovid>   {
    return this.http
        .post<PaisCovid>(environment.baseurl + environment.urlWebService.PaisRQ, data, {
            headers: this.header
        });
}
```

utilizo un componente de devextreme(devexpress) que viene siendo básicamente un mapa. Utiliza la siguiente función:

```
customizeLayers(elements) {
    elements.forEach((element) => {
        let country = this.objectMapping[element.attribute("name")];
        if(country) {
            element.applySettings({
                color: this.getCodeColor(country.Color)
            })
        }
    });
}
```

mi problema es que cuando entra al método que hace la consulta al servicio, cuando entra a la promesa, no espera hasta que traiga los datos si no que entra a la función **CustomizeLayer**, Intente agregando el async a mi método pero no funcionó para mí, lo que quiero que haga es que primero consulte el servicio cuando ya haya hecho esto, ahi si siga con los demás.
Muchas gracias por sus aportaciones y disculpen la calidad de código, soy muy nuevo programando

Comment: Saludos. En la línea `getAllContries` que pones al inicio de tu planteamiento hay '.toPromise()' quita este; te quedo a deber si se queda, cambia o quita el `then` :( no recuerdo.

Comment: Podrías mostrar dónde llamas a los métodos **customizeLayers()** y a **getAllContries()** ? Así puedo hacerme una idea de cómo quieres que funcione y pueda ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: hola a todos lo pude solucionar implementando un componente que se active solo cuando getAllCountries me retorne información desde el servicio mediante Inputs()